# Is there a way to transform lcov's coverage info file to be used with one of Hudson's coverage plug-ins?

Tags: xml, code-coverage, cobertura, emma

I am generating test code coverage using lcov (a graphical gcov tool extension). The code is compiled using Hudson and a Publish HTML plug-in is used to show results report per build. 
I lack a trend graphs available from other Hudson's coverage plug-ins.

Is there a tool/project to transform lcov's coverage output to xml format compatible with e.g. Cobertura, Emma... etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gcovr to generate a Cobertura compatible XML file.